# Want to know more about property "globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" of spring transaction management

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SpringTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="false" />
 </bean>
```

Can anyone help me to figure out that how "globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" property works in different scenarios??